# Alter clustered index column

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a clustered index on a table indexing on the `text` column. I want to switch that column with a different column like `ID`, how do I alter the index?

I can't drop and recreate because this is running on Azure and the table needs to have clustered index all the time.

The SQL command and the syntax for changing index columns in an index.

> alter index ?

Comment: Cant you add a new clustered index on the required column, and then drop the old one?

Comment: @AjoKoshy: no - you can **never** have more than one clustered index on a table!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot alter a clustered index.

The only option is to drop it and re-create it with the new column.

In your case, you'll probably have to re-create the table with the new clustered index on `ID` and then copy the data over.

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
create clustered index [your_index_name] 
on [your_table] 
   ([ID]) 
with (drop_existing = on)
```

Comment: It didn't worked for me:
Msg 1907, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot recreate index 'my_index_name'. The new index definition does not match the constraint being enforced by the existing index.

Comment: My guess is that your clustered index is also a primary key. In that case, you do need to drop and recreate.

Comment: This works great with clustered indexes no on the primary key. Thanks!

Comment: This is an insane trick! Haven't found this dispite days of searching. Thanks!